How can you make repetition on a sum equation faster?
Typing out =SUM(T2+R2+P2+N2+L2+J2+H2+F2+D2) and then changing the values is time-consuming and I'm attempting to make it faster.
I tried doing ""=SUM(Tx+Rx+Px+Nx+Lx+Jx+Hx+Fx+Dx)" (x=3)" so I would only have to change a single value, however Sheets didn't like that.

where are you entering the formula with 3 instead of 2? If it's right below the formula you shared you can simply drag it down and the rows will automatically just.

To do what you are asking for you have to use the INDIRECT function:
=LET(F,LAMBDA(x,INDIRECT(x&2)),F("T")+F("R")+F("P")+F("N")+F("L")+F("J")+F("H")+F("F")+F("D"))

(You don't need SUM since it only makes sense to use it if the argument is a range or an array.)
However, if you are trying to sum every other row from D2 to T2 there are better ways, for example:
=SUM(QUERY(TOCOL(D2:T2),"skipping 2"))

This is better because it easily scales to any sized range.

try:
=BYROW(D2:T3; LAMBDA(r; SUM(FILTER(r; ISEVEN(COLUMN(r))))))

